# Third law of motion is so confusing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

According to Newton's third law, whenever objects A and B interact with each other, they exert equal and opposite forces upon each other. I have always struggled with how to apply this law to problems and real life.

> Suppose I get a pull from my friend with some force, then I get pulled forward by  a large distance as compared to the distance covered by my friend. Isn't this a case where Newton's third law of motion fails?  Or, does this happen because of the difference in our masses?

My second question is about the tension in the rope in Atwood's Machine (two unequal masses connected by a rope on either side of a friction-less pulley). http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atwd.html I have solved various pulley mass problems but I have not thought about applying Newton's Third Law of Motion to it.

> Is tension the counterforce to weight? Consider a segment of rope from which a  mass is suspended in Atwood's Machine.  That segment will experience a force $m1g$ from the weight. People say this weight is the reason for the counterforce in that segment, and that this force will travel all the way through the rope to the other segment resulting in a uniform tension.  If this is correct then I can see the uniform tension around the rope as an application of newton's third law but the fact  that this resulted from the weight negates the third law and also this will mean that m1=m2 where m1 and m2 are the masses at each segment
>   ...can somebody explain this to me

Comment: A more vivid example of the first case is a horse pulling a sleigh. By Newton's third law, the force that the horse exerts on the sleigh is equal to the force that the sleigh exerts on the horse. It's only when we account the friction and the ground that we are able to understand that the duo moves horse-ward.

Comment: @svavil Ah but real life is so complicated ;-). Are you suggesting that the friction force on the sleigh is smaller than the force with which the horse pulls? I don't thinks so (for constant velocity). If we assume, for the sake of argument, that the frictional force does not depend on the sleigh's velocity (and mind you, in reality the friction is probably *weaker* once the sleigh is moving!); then the force needed to keep the sleigh moving is not larger than the force needed to get it going from still-stand. The two are in equilibrium at constant velocity, even going backwards!

Comment: @svavil (ctd. ...) Big difference to the accelerating masses in Atwood's machine, where there is no equilibrium.

Comment: If it wasn't like this, then hitting a hammer with an egg would not produce the same results as hitting the egg with the hammer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you and your friend are interacting, when he pulls you, he will feel that you apply to him the same force as he applies to you. If both of you are in vacuum and no further forces are present, the change in momentum will be equal for both of you. If further forces like friction are present, then the total forces acting on each of you might differ. But the parts which come due to you two interacting with each other will still be equal.

In the rope example there are two things playing a role and they should be kept apart:

1. Each segment of the rope acts on any of the adjacent segments with the same force as the adjacent segment acts on it. Here we are looking at forces acting on different objects interacting with each other. This is Newton's 3rd law.
2. The weight and the rope (and thus each segment of the rope) are in a force equilibrium, so the total force on each segment exercised by both adjacent segments totals to zero. Here we are looking at the forces on one object exercised by all other objects it interacts with.

While the first point is always true, the second one doesn't have to be true, say, if the rope and the weight are in a free fall accelerating towards the earth, rather than in an equilibrium situation. Obviously, there will be no tension force in case that the second point is not given.

Comment: I understood the role of newton's third law in the first case but can you explain the second case some more as i have edited some parts in it.Sry for disturbing you

Comment: Say, you enumerate your segments from 1 to n. The weight is in equilibrium, so it feels two equal forces: $F_w=mg$ pulling it down and $F_1=F_w$ by the first segment of the rope pulling it up (this is point 2, equilibrium). The force pulling down the first segment from this interaction is again $F_1$ (this is point 1, Newtons law). Now, the first segment is in equilibrium as well, so it has to be pulled up with the same force (it is acted on by the second segment) as it is pulled down by the weight, so we have $F_2=F_1$. But now we know that the same force $F_2$ pulls the second segment down..

Comment: So you see, that in each step we have to apply both points: equilibrium condition and Newton's 3rd law. One of them ensures that the forces on each segment by its neighbours are equal (and total to zero due to different signs), the other one ensures that forces with which each pair of segments act on each other are equal as well. In total we have the same force throughout the whole rope.

Comment: So each segment will remain at equilibrium as this goes on.......what will tension force be here...F1,F2...etc?

Comment: Now thinking this I got the idea about what is happening in equilibrium condition but I am now confused for the non-equilibrium part.How will tension vary for that case when both masses are accelerating

Comment: Well, $F_n=F_{n-1}=...=F_2=F_1=F_w=mg$, so all involved forces are equal.

Comment: If there is no equilibrium, it means that some net force is acting on some of the involved bodies. This may be the case if the whole rope and weight are falling, or if the rope is stretchable and we are in the process of stretching it. In such cases we cannot assume equilibrium.

Comment: Will Tension become less in that case but also will it still be same throughout because i think newton's third law should for it also?

Comment: Well, this is hard to say in this generality, but let's consider an example: If you take a rubber band and pull it apart, then its middle point is fixed while its end points are accelerated maximally (by your hands), the acceleration of other segments ranges somewhere between zero and the maximal one. So the forces of the neighbours of a segment will not sum up to zero in general (only for the segment in the exact middle of the band they will). Therefore, I'd expect the tension to be maximal at the ends and minimal in the middle.

Comment: @Photon a doubt, In space, if an astronaut pulls anything, does he/she moving in pulled direction?

Comment: If he pulls something towards himself, he will move towards the object he is pulling (in total, they will move towards each other).

Comment: @Photon Imagine a pulley system where one end of rope is attached to a mass and other to a spring which is fixed to the ground which are initally at equilibrium.When the mass is displaced downwards,Will the tension force be equal to spring force?

Comment: @GENESECT When the displacement is without acceleration - yes. But when acceleration is non-zero, then no.

Comment: @Photon How does displacemet without acceleration bring that change...can you pls explain this too me.If I just displace the mass by some distance downwards,why is tension equal to spring force.How does Newton's third law play here

Comment: @GENESECT Because if the acceleration is zero, all bodies involved are in force equilibrium and then the explanation in my first comment (from   Jan 21 at 11:04) applies: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381299/third-law-of-motion-is-so-confusing/381324?noredirect=1#comment854647_381324

Comment: @Photon So the body has to  be in equilibrium for third law to work on in this case

Comment: @GENESECT I think since we can consider to be made of many parts therefore displacing without acceleration would bring non zero force on the part attached at the end of mass and therefore by Newton's third law they would travel all around the rope and ultimately become equal to the spring force on the other end...........I am not too sure about this tho

Comment: @GENESECT: No. These are two different things as I stated in the initial answer. Let us consider a segment of a rope which is accelerated to the left. Since it is accelerated, the force pulling it to the left is larger than the force pulling it to the right. But it pulls the right neighbour with the same force which it is being pulled by it, same with the left neighbour. So: $F(\text{left neighbour acting on segment}) = F(\text{segment acting on left neighbour}) > F(\text{right neighbour acting on segment}) = F(\text{segment acting on right neighbour})$

Comment: The equalities follow from Newton's third law, the inequality results from the system being accelerated and thus not in force equilibrium.

Comment: @Photon So the leftmost segment will feel exact pulling force from the pulling force which will be greater than the force it recieves from the right so it will result in disturbing the equality between the segments

Comment: @GENESECT: Exactly!

Comment: @Photon So does this mean that if the force on a body is zero and it is being feeling effect from any force then it will create a counter force to negate that effect like applying force to a massless pulley will negate the effect through the tension acting on it

Comment: @GENESECT: Not sure if I understand you correctly. If body 1 is applying a force on body 2, then, by Newton's law, body 2 applies exactly the same force (in opposite direction) to body 1. Since the forces act on different bodies, none of them is in force equilibrium. However, if further forces are present, it can happen that they are indeed in equilibrium.

Comment: @Photon Okay.Thanx for the help

Comment: @GENESECT: You're welcome!

Comment: @Photon Is my logic Correct

Comment: @Photon That's a lot of my comment lol.Reading this got me a doubt about this part :(When the displacement is without acceleration - yes. But when acceleration is non-zero, then no. ).Why is the weight of the block not equal to tension if the rope has an acceleration zero.Sry for disturbing you

Comment: @harambe: I'm not sure I understand your explanation, could you please rephrase it?
 HydrousCaperilla: If the rope has no acceleration, then the weight is equal to the tension, yes, that's about what I wrote in the passage you cited. :)

Comment: @Photon When the mass was displaced downwardss with no acceleration then you said that tension is equal to spring force but what happened  to weight.....Did it get neglected

Comment: As far as I understand, the objects are connected like this: spring----rope----weight. In this case the spring force is equal to the tension force of the rope is equal to the weight, if the system is in equilibrium (that is, not accelerated).

Comment: @Photon  if the rope is not massless then will there be variable tension everywhere?

Comment: @magemaro: I think so. Since the lowest segment of the rope feels almost no force from below, while the highest segment feels almost the complete weight of the rope.

Comment: @Photon so if i enumerate the strings to 1,2.....n segments then at each segment the mass of that segment will be added to the force felt by the lowermost segment which gets transferred due to newton's third law,right?

Comment: @magemaro: Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

The motion of you and your friend depends on all the forces which are acting on you you and your masses.

When you pull your friend forward although the forces between you and your friend are equal in magnitude what about the force that you bother experience due to the Earth?

Assuming that you had equal masses if net force on your friend is greater than the net force on you then your friend will undergo a greater acceleration.

Mass will a play a part and so when you start walking towards the front of a moving train the change is speed is not noticeable although it possibly would be if you were in a small boat whose mass is much less than that of the train and thus closer to your mass.

---

The Atwood machine with one pulley can be thought of being equivalent to the following example.

[image]

Where the two masses at the ends of the rope are called $1$ and $3$ and the rope $2$ but you could extend it to being a whole string of as many masses as you wish.

The masses at the ends of the rope are subjected to gravitational attractive forces and the Newton third law force are labelled $F_{12}$ etc where $F_{12}$ is the force on mass $1$ due to mass $2$, the rope.

Taking towards the right as positive and applying Newton's second law gives.

$$m_3g-F_{32} = m_3a \;\;\; F_{23}-F_{21} = m_2a  \;\;\;  F_{12}-m_1g = m_1a $$
where is the acceleration of all the masses as the rope is assumed to be inextensible.

It is often the case that the rope is assumed to be massless which means that $F_{23}-F_{21} = 0 \Rightarrow F_{23} = F_{21}$ and these forces are called the tension in the rope.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of unequal masses attached to a massless rope supported by a frictionless pulley, the tension in the rope is the same everywhere within the rope. Using *m1* to represent the smaller mass and *m2* to represent the larger mass, and *a* to represent the rate of acceleration, then

tension = *m1* (*g* + *a*) = *m2* (*g* - *a*)

where

*a* = (*m2*-*m1*) *g* / (*m1*+*m2*)

The same formulas apply for *m1* >= *m2*, corresponding to *a* <= 0.

Answer (score 2):

When you pull your friend both experience difference forces, you travel different distances because of several other factors (friction, mass, etc.)

Yes tension is created as a reaction to the weight but only when the mass attached to the string is  not accelerating, in accelerating system the tension is the counter force to the force exerted by the particle on the string (not always equal to the weight).

Answer (score -1):

When you are being pulled by your friend, the action is **your friend pulling** and the reaction is **you moving forwards**. That's the Third law. Now you move a bit ahead after he stops : because

1. Probably the force was increased momentarily before he stopped.
2. He kept pulling even after stopping.
3. Quoting First Law of motion, an object in motion tends to remain in motion unless an external force acts on it. So you moved an extra distance until the external force of friction made you finally stop.

For simplicity, I consider tension as the opposite of compression. It is like friction. There is a limiting value of tension exceeding which the rope snaps. Tension is indeed the counter force of weight. It acts only when weight is present and that too in the direction of the string, opposite to the weight. Just as a reaction force. As per Third Law, the weight when attached to string must exert a force on the string (action) the string initiated a pulling force in the opposite direction to keep it attached (reaction) which is tension. So there.

It is indeed uniformly distributed in Atwoods machine. Only a massless string would have that. Even if 2kg and 5kg were attached to both ends the tension would have been uniformly distributed. How else would you explain the resultant acceleration if tension were localised? That's why the string moves because of residual force of 30N in my case. Tension balanced 2kg for 20N and 5kg for 50N and the rest caused acceleration. Here too the residual force 30N exerted on the string (action) caused a net acceleration (reaction). I hope this theory helps.

Comment: -1 When the action is your friend pulling you, the reaction is **you pulling your friend**. This is the 3rd Law. Whether or not you **move** and in which direction depends on the resultant of all forces acting on you, not only the force applied by your friend.